# place button at bottom of div

Tags: css

i have number of divs are available in my webpage. For each div one  button is there.
My requirement is place this button at bottom for every div irrespective of the size of the div.
 Please give me some solution for this.

Comment: Do you want to add it dynamically using javascript or as static content?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the div in another div, and put the button directly after it, like this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        Main contents of Div
    </div>
    <button>Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Or even wrap the button in its own div should give the same effect.